# Limit module position output to only 1, in Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, templates, joomla1.5

I'm familiar with `$this->countModules()` and `getModule()`, but what I am looking to do is limit the output of specific module positions to the first module. I'm aware that I could customize which pages modules are set to output on, or that with CSS I could visually hide those extra modules.

Is there any way to limit amount of modules for a single module position within a template?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

no, Joomla is flexible enough to give the administrator the rights what should be displayed or not on a particular module position but there is no other way for you to limit the amount of modules for a single module position, but if you really want to have this for your joomla installation then you have no other option but to modify the core codes but that is too risky then.